# Mail Merge: Print two recipients in one page

Tags: excel, ms-word, mailmerge

I just want to ask if it is possible to show different recipients in one page using the Mail Merge function in MS Word? The bottom recipient must be the data of "Name 2". If not possible, any suggestions on how can I print it in one page?

MS Word:

[image: SAMPLE]

MS Excel:

[image: SAMPLE]

Comment: This is not a programming question and, as such, is off-topic for Stack Overflow. Questions on general usage of Microsoft Word should be asked on an appropriate end-use forum (e.g., MS Answers). As for the question itself, the solution is trivial - use a label merge with a suitable label/table format...

Comment: The answer to your basic question is "Yes." You need to ask elsewhere. Your question is ***off-topic*** here and likely will be closed without answers. The confusion is understandable. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic  This would be an appropriate question on the **Microsoft Community** http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word or on **Super User** https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-word or other forums.

Comment: Noted on this. I'm so sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. For second recipient follow the below steps-

> From mailings-->Rules-->Next Record

[image]